# mysql ndb cluster "information_schema.tables" query

Tags: mysql, sql, time, information-schema

I am using Mysql NDB Cluster, in my information_schema.Tables tbl I have null entries in the column called Create_Time and Update_Time.

Does anyone have any known solution for this.

As on my normal innodb databases the Create_Time and Update_Time is there properly.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran across this behavior and can't find an official solution. I am treating that null date field as DateTime.MinValue in my code.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski